# Resize react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

Is it possible to adjust the height of the the droppable container? I tried inline styling

`<Droppable droppableId="list" style={{ height: 200 }}>`

but didn't yield expected results. My expectation is that the container that holds the draggable items can be adjust to a certain height x and the overflow of draggable items will be scrollable. I also tried wrapping `<DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>` with the following `div` tag:

`<div style={{ height: 200 }}>`

https://codesandbox.io/s/using-react-beautiful-dnd-with-hooks-qnez5

Answer (score 1):

You can give inline styling and conditional styles too.
As shown in the code below its inline styling.

```
 <Droppable
         droppableId={`${laneItem.Value}`}
         type="TASK"
         key={`droppable-${laneItem.Value}`}
       >
       {(provided) => (
           <div
              id={laneItem.Value}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              key={`droppable-div-${laneItem.Value} - ${index + 1}`}
              style={{ height: '200px' }}
        >
```

Here it is conditional styling,

```
 <Droppable
         droppableId={`${laneItem.Value}`}
         type="TASK"
         key={`droppable-${laneItem.Value}`}
       >
       {(provided) => (
           <div
              id={laneItem.Value}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              key={`droppable-div-${laneItem.Value} - ${index + 1}`}
              styles={true ? bigHeight : smallHeight}
        >
```

where big-Height and small-Height are const.

```
const big-Height: any = {
root: {
height: "200px"
  }
}
```